# Orchard CMS: getting post URL as a string

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

How do I get the URL of a certain post and an uploaded image from within the `Content-BlogPost.cshtml` alternate as a string?

[EDIT]

Link:

I can access the ContentItem of my blog post via `Model.ContentItem.BlogPostPart.ContentItem`.  I can access the title and published date,   via `Model.ContentItem.BlogPostPart.Title` and `Model.ContentItem.BlogPostPart.PublishedUtc` respectively. I can't find any URL field there though.

I know I can generate a link tag using `@Html.ItemDisplayLink(Title, ContentItem)` but I want to get the URL string as it is.

Comment: This question needs more details: what do you have about the linked post? Id, a reference? What was the uploaded image uploaded with? What do you know about it? Id, path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution is as simple as using `@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(contentItem)`:

```
@{
ContentItem item = Model.ContentItem.BlogPostPart.ContentItem;
}
<a href='@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(item)'>link</a>
```

I will now mark this as an answer and create a new question for the media image question.